# How to check the unique rows of the receiver table of Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

I need to move rows between tables of Tabulator. How can I check the unique rows of the receiver when I move rows from the sender to the receiver?

Answer (score 1):

[Callbacks](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/move)
The rowMoved callback will be triggered when a row has been successfuly moved. You can use this function to trigger any ajax requests or other updates needed upon a successful row move.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowMoved:function(row){
        //row - row component
    }
});
```